# Call stored function mongodb java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, stored-procedures

I have a problem executing stored function on MongoDB from my java code , i have a stored function like this.

```
db.system.js.save({

  _id:"myFunction",
  value:function(data){
    //todo        
    return 1 + 1;
   }
});
```

And in my java code :

```
mongoClient = new MongoClient(SERVER, PORT); // should use this always
db = mongoClient.getDB(DB);
DBObject datos = new BasicDBObject();
datos.put("val", "myvalue");
```

Then i am trying to execute the function:

try 1

```
db.doEval("myFunction", datos);
```

try 2

```
db.eval("myFunction", datos);
```

try 3

```
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("myFunction", datos);
db.command(query);
```

But the stored function does not execute, any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved, it seems to pass values/objects to the stored function you have to serialize the object as JSON, so I did this :

```
String values = JSON.serialize(datos);
```

Then my java code looks like :

```
CommandResult er = db.doEval("myFunction("+values+")");
```

And the stored function gets executed correctly.